# MIPS assembly language programming

Tags: assembly, floating-point, decimal, mips, mars-simulator

Hello I am currently learning MIPS assembly language programming. I am trying to print the answer truncated to only one decimal place. For example 127.0 instead of 127.000000 but it is still printing 127.000000 Thank you for your help.

Here is the code:

```
  .data

  height: .asciiz "Height of right triangle: "
  width:  .asciiz "\nWidth of right triangle: "
  result: .asciiz "\nArea of right triangle is "
  height_input: .float 0.0
  width_input:  .float 0.0
  result_input: .float 0.0
  divide_by_2:  .float 2.0


     ###########################################################
    .text
    main:
li $v0, 4       # print string syscall
la $a0, height  # load the address of height
syscall

li $v0, 6   # read float syscall
syscall
s.s $f0, height_input   # move input into the register for height

li $v0, 4   # print string syscall
la $a0, width   # load the address of width
syscall

li $v0, 6   # read float syscall
syscall
s.s $f0, width_input    # move input into the register for width

l.s $f0, height_input
l.s $f1, width_input
l.s $f4, divide_by_2
mul.s $f2, $f0, $f1 # multiply height times width
div.s $f3, $f2, $f4   # divide by 2 to get the area

# now we want to truncate to have only one decimal point

li $t5, 100
mtc1 $t5, $f5
cvt.s.w $f5, $f5
mul.s $f3, $f3, $f5
trunc.w.s $f3, $f3
cvt.s.w $f3, $f3
div.s $f3, $f3, $f5
s.s $f3, result_input


li $v0, 4   # print string syscall
la $a0, result  # load address of result
syscall

li $v0, 2   # print float syscall
l.s $f12, result_input   # move the area into the f12 register to print
syscall

j exit      # jump to the exit subroutine to end the program

exit:
    li $v0, 10              # exit program
    syscall
###########################################################
```

Comment: That may be a limitation of the print float syscall (haven't tested though). Anyway, as a workaround, print the two parts as integers, with a dot between them.

Comment: Thanks Jester for the awesome advice !! I have been programming for 20 years but just getting started with assembly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing to do with MIPS as an ISA, everything to do with the toy system-call API that MARS and SPIM provide.  (With no control parameters for double -> string conversion like you could do with `printf`, or if you implemented the conversion yourself by hand.  But note that double -> string and the reverse are notoriously difficult to do accurately for all corner cases of large/small numbers, and also efficiently.)  e.g. calling `printf` on MIPS GNU/Linux would work like any other printf.  For a toy program on MARS I'd consider just letting it print trailing zeros.

Comment: I was over thinking this. I was only required to enter integer values for height and width. so the decimal part will be either .0 or .5 depending if (height * width mod 2) if it does not have a remainder append .0 if it has a remainder append .5 to the value. I checked the value of the HI register to accomplish this. Program now works great. I would post full working code but the university that I am taking the class at does not want full solutions posted online.